# Alternative to md5, also available in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, encryption, hash, md5

As php.net states [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php):

> It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to
>   the fast nature of this hashing algorithm.

I have used the `md5` function since I started programming with PHP, but after researching, it is clear that `md5` is discouraged and an alternative should be used.

I am aware of a possible alternative, `sha1`. **Are there any others as well?**

**What are the benefits of these other ones, and `sha1` (excluding higher security)?**

**And most importantly, can a `sha1` hash or any of the other hashing algorithms be replicated in javascript?**

I have an `md5` plugin in javascript and it is key to some of my secure applications. Therefore, having a hashing algorithm that has a javascript plugin is absolutely essential.

Comment: About the SHA-1 in Javascript, check out the [php.js](http://phpjs.org/) project and take a look at the `sha1` function.

Comment: Check out [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for JavaScript hashing functions.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Are they also available in PHP though?

Comment: @BenCarey - Yes, most of them. The one you asked about, SHA-1, is. You can use the PHP [`hash_algos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) function to see a list of hashing functions available to your PHP build.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Yup, can see that, thank you. What I would like to know though, is, which one should I be using? Is `sha1` recommended?

Comment: the answer to "can x be done in y?" is always "yes", as long as x is computable and y is turing complete `;-)`. It's better to ask "is x available in y as a library function?"

Comment: @BenCarey - That particular question might be better suited to http://security.stackexchange.com. There may well already be an answer to it there.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Felt it would be better suited here because it depends on the language, not the security

Comment: You should use neither MD5 nor SHA1 to secure passwords, crypt() is the preffered way to do this http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php you should also apply a salt to your passwords. I am not aware of any Blowfish encryptors in JS, but a quick search on the interwebs should do it. If you are just after making text unreadable, SHA256 and SHA512 is recommended. The problem with MD5 and SHA1 is that there are a few collissions, which are text that return the same hash. http://www.md5decrypter.co.uk/ will show you what I mean.

Comment: @MartinRisell-Lilja I am more than aware of how to use these functions and how essential it is to apply salts to them. I am not a newbie to PHP security. I simply want advice on which function to use, and why. But one of the essential factors that will influence my decision is whether or not there is a javascript equivalent of the function. Which with `crypt()`, there is not! Furthermore, there are always going to be collisions for any hashing algorithm, think of it logically, it is impossible for there not to be!

Comment: @BenCarey It should be possible to emulate crypt using a combination of JS libraries, or maybe just a Blowfish lib. Thought there are loads of SHA256 and SHA512 libraries for JavaScript. It all depends of what you want to prioritize, I think, for example, Gravatar still uses MD5 to send e-mail addresses. Then speed and availability is prioritized over less collisions.

Comment: What do you use it for? For normal hashing SHA256 is the way to go. For password hashing you should use scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Most cases it will be used for password hashing

Comment: I'd be rather interested where you apply the hash in Javascript as a "key to your security". Can't this be replaced with a server-only scheme of securing whatever you're trying to secure?

Comment: @deceze It is purely to transmit through to a PHP page where it is encrypted further. This is to just make sniffing a little harder, obviously not 100% secure but it is a little more secure, especially when not using HTTPS

Comment: When not using HTTPS, most bets are off anyway. If someone can sniff the traffic between client and server and you're not using a robust zero-knowledge-nonce-backed protocol, whether you send encrypted data or not hardly matters. Also, if someone is in a position to sniff the data, they're often also in a position to mount MITM attacks. If you use client-side hashes for "just a little extra over an insecure connection", chances are it's not enough to bother with to begin with.

Comment: @BenCarey Without HTTPS you're doomed. Javascript crypto can't replace HTTPS.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I use HTTPS on all of my larger sites, but the minor ones with basic management logins do not always have HTTPS and this just adds another level of security albeit minor :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SHA1 and MD5 have pretty much the same weakness: Their collision resistance is broken. So when MD5 is wrong, so is SHA1. Their output is also a bit short. If collision resistance is required, I recommend at least 256 bit hashes. More than 256 bits are rarely necessary.

For normal hashing applications SHA-256 (part of the SHA-2 family) is a good choice. While it's performance isn't too great, nobody has broken its collision resistance so far. You can also go with SHA-3-256, but the library support isn't that great yet.

For password hashing you need a specialized construction, such as scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2. Use a unique salt and a sufficient iteration count. Do not use a plain hash, they're too fast.

For MAC(Message Authentication) use a specialized construction, such as HMAC-SHA-256 and not plain SHA-256.

---

The upcoming [WebCryptoAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI) will contain functions for most of these operations.

Until it gets deployed, you can use [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js) which offers both PBKDF2 and SHA-256.

---

But I'm a bit doubtful about your architecture. Hashing passwords in javascript is rarely the right choice. Standard procedure is using SSL/TLS and sending the plaintext password over it. You cannot achieve security with in browser javascript unless you use TLS.

Comment: Please see my comment to @GiulioMuscarello's answer. You have answered my question to an extent so +1, but I it really lies on whether or not I can find a javascript plugin to replicate the PHP function.

Comment: Is the crypto API javascript?

Comment: Sending a password from one page to another, whether it be via ajax or form submitting will always expose the data being sent, unless it is over HTTPS. Hashing the passwords client side, just adds another level of security (albeit minor, and crackable) to the application. That is why :-)

Comment: @BenCarey Hashing the password client side for *transmission* provides nothing as far as security goes. You just made the hash of the password the password. Think of it this way: You and I agree to identify each other by the codeword "Potato". One day, you realize that someone may listen to you as you identify, so you say to me: "OK, from now on I will *hash* the codeword and tell you that instead so we can stay safe!" But since "Potato" always hashes to "123456789" what stops someone who overheard "123456789" without knowing that the "real" keyword is "Potato" from repeating it?

Comment: @NikB. I agree, however, it adds one level of security in the fact that they still do not know what was typed into the form

Comment: @NikB. True. So add a serial number and/or today's date to each message's password and hash that, i.e, first message's password is 'Potato0' which might hash to "123456789".  For the next message hash 'Potato1' which yeilds something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many other hashing algorithms as well, much stronger than `SHA1`. Check `SHA512`, for example: it has 512 bits against, for example, 128 bits for `MD5`.
Anyway, if you're looking for real safety, you should apply one of the following:

1) "Fixed salt": instead of `md5($pass)`, you use:

```
$salt="NaCl";
$hash=md5($salt);
```

2) "Random salt": instead of md5($pass)', you generate a random salt (use the function `rand($minValue, $maxValue)`) with a great range (say `rand(0, pow(10, 100))` and use `md5($pass, $salt)`. **Don't forget to store BOTH the hash and the salt!**

3) Encryption: you use either a fixed or a random key (see the precedent method), and use it to encrypt the password. I'd really suggest the Blowfish algorithm.
From the [page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) on PHP.net:

```
<?php
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "This is a very secret key";
    $text = "Meet me at 11 o'clock behind the monument.";
    echo strlen($text) . "\n";

    $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    echo strlen($crypttext) . "\n";
?>
```

Implementing SHA512 in JavaScript (without the salt generation) (from [the CryptoJS library](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)):

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/sha512.js"></s‌​cript>
<script> var hash = CryptoJS.SHA512("Message"); </script>
```

Implementing bcrypt in JavaScript: see [this example](http://javascript-bcrypt.googlecode.com/hg/example.html).

Comment: Also, an explaination of why 512 is better than sha512 is better than md5 and sha1: sha512 is 512 bits long, while md5 is 128 and sha1 is - afaik - 256 bits. Hence, it is much more probable to find a collision (two strings with the same hash) with md5 than with sha512.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as much as I appreciate your help, I am already aware or salting and why sha512 is more secure etc... I am not a newbie to PHP security. My question was simply, which is the most secure and does it exist as a javascript plugin? You have answered my question to a certain extent so I will give you +1, but what I am really looking for is a clear indication of which hashing algorithm to use (you have done this), and a link to an open source javascript plugin that includes this algorithm. If you can supply that then I will accept your answer.

Comment: Quite a few flaws. 1) ECB mode 2) putting a string directly into the IV. 3) MD5 for password hashing 4) Bad salt creation. 5) Encryption vulnerable to padding oracles (And as a minor issue, why no AES?)

Comment: @GiulioMuscarello You need to amend your answer, not add to the comments